# Using minitest to test that hash contains array values of specific size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, minitest

How would one test that the returned value from a method contains a hash with values that are arrays of elements of no less than 3 and no greater than 5?

Here is the hash:

```
{455=>[638205575, 298486374, 51848956, 113629430], 310=>[457008489, 587967610, 241469500, 991788158], 430=>[1047793131, 510532105, 1018350795, 281110143, 980190962]}
```

I would show my attempts at this, but they're pathetic. I'm still wrapping my head around testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a more elegant solution, but how about something like this:

```
array_of_element_lengths = result_of_method.map {|_key, value| value.length}
assert array_of_element_lengths.min >= 3 && array_of_element_lengths.max <= 5
```

Comment: @isea That's just testing that there are between 3 and 5 elements. Do you also need to test that the returned value is a hash whose values are arrays?

Comment: That worked great. I can probably figure that one out. Frankly, I should have been able to do this too.Thank you